# Future Value calculator and Exponents

Tags: c

Im trying to make a Future value calculator and am not allowed to use the power function. The formula to calculate future value is future value = principal * ( 1 + rate ) ^ (number of periods). Now you cannot use the ^ for exponents in C so i tried using the base and exponent concept which gives me the closest answer to whats expected but still is not right. It gives me a value but its not the correct answer and is too large. If you require more information please ask.

Test run:

## Investment Calculator

Principal  : 1000
Annual Rate: 0.06
No of Years: 5
The future value is $1338225577600000.000000

the expected result is $1338.23.

```
#include<stdio.h>

double FutureVal(double prin, double rate,int years);

int main()
{

    double principal;
    double annualRate;
    int  NumYears;
    double result;


    printf("Investment Calculator\n");
    printf("=====================\n");

    printf("Principal  : ");
    scanf("%lf",&principal);

    printf("Annual Rate: ");
    scanf("%lf",&annualRate);

    printf("No of Years: ");
    scanf("%d",&NumYears);

    result = FutureVal(principal,annualRate,NumYears);

    printf("The future value is $%lf \n",result);

    return 0;

}

double FutureVal(double prin, double rate, int years)
{
    int i;
    double value = (prin * ( 1 + rate)) ;
    double result = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < years; i++)
    {
            result *= value;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code to see where the calculation goes wrong?

Comment: Im sorry its C. its just that whenever i google for help typing C gives you many results so i assumed its called C#.

Comment: Why did you use value = (prin * ( 1 + rate)) ;......... Shouldn't it just be value = ( 1 + rate);

Answer (score 0):

The function below would do the task:

```
double FutureVal(double prin, double rate, int years)
{
    int i;
    double value = 1 + rate ;
    double result = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < years; i++)
    {
            result *= value;
    }
    result *= prin;
    return result;
}
```

Since in the formula for finding the amount its

```
prin * ((1+rate)^years)
```

and what you are doing is :

```
(prin*(1+rate))^years
```

That's the reason for the incorrect ouput

PS: If you want to display just 2 digit after the decimal as mentioned by you, use:

```
 printf("The future value is $%.2lf \n",result);
```

in the main method after the function call